# Fitting Logarithmic Regression line

Tags: python, regression

I am trying to implement logarithmic regression using SciPy curve fit. However, it is returning a line instead.

[image: This is the result I'm getting]

[image: Dataframe used]

Code:

```py
def plotVideoPerformance(df):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

    #Data Points
    x = df['period']
    y = df['estimated_revenue_total']
    title = df['title'].unique()

    #Regression Functions  
    def log_func(x,a,b):
        return a+b*np.log(x)    

    #Find optimal params
    log_popt, log_pcov = curve_fit(log_func,mdates.date2num(x), y)
    
    log_params = f"a=%.2f,b=%.2f" % tuple(log_popt)

    log_reg = log_func(mdates.date2num(x),*log_popt)

    plt.scatter(x, y)
    plt.plot(x,log_reg,'b', label=log_params)
```

Comment: Can you please share some of the sample data points of `df` for experimenting? I think `curve fit` is not able to find the best fit.

Comment: There's nothing wrong and it is the best fit.  The function you specified will appear linear for large enough values.  Your problem is you chose an inflexible function to fit with given your data using `date2num`.

Comment: Please replace your dataframe image with a block of code that, when executed, produces a dataframe that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Image are very poor medium to exchange textual data. Do you expect each user that want to help to re input it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the functions correctly but the `curve-fit` is not able to find the proper fit for the log functions which is making it difficult for it to converge to a solution. You can try taking the `log` of both `x` and `y` before fitting.

```py
def plotVideoPerformance(df):
    # ...other code
    #Take log of x and y
    log_x = np.log(mdates.date2num(x))
    log_y = np.log(y)
    linear_popt, linear_pcov = curve_fit(linear_func,log_x, log_y)
    # ... rest of code
```

***[CODE DEMO](https://trinket.io/python3/23c878929d)***

Answer (score 0):

Changing the logarithmic function to a X-shifted equation of `y = a * ln(x + b)` was the solution to this problem.

Reference - [*Python using curve_fit to fit a logarithmic function*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59805561/python-using-curve-fit-to-fit-a-logarithmic-function)